# Most optimized way to filter patch positions in an image

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

So my problem is this: I have an RGB image as a numpy array of dimensions `(4086, 2048, 3)`, I split this image dimension into 96x96 patches and get back the **positions** of these patches in a numpy array. I **always** get 96x96 patches in every case. If the dimensions of the image can't allow me to create "pure" 96x96 patches on the x or y axis I just add a left padding to it so the last patches overlap a bit with the patch before it.

Now with these positions in hand I want to get rid of all 96x96 patches for which the RGB value is `255` in all three channels for every pixel in the patch, in **the fastest way possible** and I want to get back all the patches **positions** which don't have this value.

I would like to know:

1. What is the fastest way to extract the 96x96 patches positions from the image dimension? (for now I have a for loop)
2. How can you get rid of pure white patches (with value `255` on the 3 channels) in **most optimal way**? (for now I have a for loop)

I have a lot of these images to process like that with images resolution going up to `(39706, 94762, 3)` so my "for loops" becomes quickly inefficient here. Thanks for your help! (I take solutions which make use of the GPU too)

Here is the pseudo code to give you an idea on how it's done for now:

```
patches = []
patch_y = 0
y_limit = False
slide_width = 4086
slide_height = 2048
# Lets imagine this image_slide has 96x96 patches which value is 255
image_slide = np.random.rand(slide_width, slide_height, 3)
while patch_y < slide_height:
    patch_x = 0
    x_limit = False
    while patch_x < slide_width:
        # Extract the patch at the given position and return it or return None if it's 3 RGB
        # channels are 255
        is_white = PatchExtractor.is_white(patch_x, patch_y, image_slide)

        # Add the patches position to the list if it's not None (not white)
        if not is_white:
            patches.append((patch_x, patch_y))

        if not x_limit and patch_x + crop_size > slide_width - crop_size:
            patch_x = slide_width - crop_size
            x_limit = True
        else:
            patch_x += crop_size
    if not y_limit and patch_y + crop_size > slide_height - crop_size:
        patch_y = slide_height - crop_size
        y_limit = True
    else:
        patch_y += crop_size

return patches
```

Ideally, I would like to get my patches positions outside a "for loop" then once I have them I can test if they are white or not **outside a for loop** as well with the fewer possible calls to numpy (so the code is processed in the C layer of numpy and doesn't go back and forth to python)

Comment: Share your working loopy solutions?

Comment: I just edited my question :)

Comment: I made a gpu solution and realized ~90% of time is spent on transferring data from ram to gpu :(

Comment: @ShihabShahriar you used numba or something to move your arrays to the GPU?

Comment: pytorch actually

Comment: The answer provided by @AndreasDeak is very good by unfortunately it doesn't respect my conditions at 100%. I need to have 96x96 images and the ones at the edges must have a left and top paddings and **must not resize the original image** like in Andreas answer with `np.pad`, this is very important. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected you can vectorize all of what you're doing. It takes roughly a small integer multiple of the memory need of your original image. The algorithm is quite straightforward: pad your image so that an integer number of patches fit in it, cut it up into patches, check if each patch is all white, keep the rest:

```
import numpy as np                                                                    

# generate some dummy data and shapes
imsize = (1024, 2048)
patchsize = 96
image = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=imsize + (3,), dtype=np.uint8)
# seed some white patches: cut a square hole in the random noise
image[image.shape[0]//2:3*image.shape[0]//2, image.shape[1]//2:3*image.shape[1]//2] = 255

# pad the image to necessary size; memory imprint similar size as the input image
# white pad for simplicity for now
nx,ny = (np.ceil(dim/patchsize).astype(int) for dim in imsize) # number of patches
if imsize[0] % patchsize or imsize[1] % patchsize:
    # we need to pad along at least one dimension
    padded = np.pad(image, ((0, nx * patchsize - imsize[0]),
                            (0, ny * patchsize - imsize[1]), (0,0)),
                    mode='constant', constant_values=255)
else:
    # no padding needed
    padded = image

# reshape padded image according to patches; doesn't copy memory
patched = padded.reshape(nx, patchsize, ny, patchsize, 3).transpose(0, 2, 1, 3, 4) 
# patched is shape (nx, ny, patchsize, patchsize, 3)
# appending .copy() as a last step to the above will copy memory but might speed up
# the next step; time it to find out

# check for white patches; memory imprint the same size as the padded image
filt = ~(patched == 255).all((2, 3, 4))
# filt is a bool, one for each patch that tells us if it's _not_ all white
# (i.e. we want to keep it)

patch_x,patch_y = filt.nonzero() # patch indices of non-whites from 0 to nx-1, 0 to ny-1
patch_pixel_x = patch_x * patchsize  # proper pixel indices of each pixel
patch_pixel_y = patch_y * patchsize
patches = np.array([patch_pixel_x, patch_pixel_y]).T
# shape (npatch, 2) which is compatible with a list of tuples

# if you want the actual patches as well:
patch_images = patched[filt, ...]
# shape (npatch, patchsize, patchsize, 3),
# patch_images[i,...] is an image with patchsize * patchsize pixels
```

As you can see, in the above I used white padding to get a congruent padded image. I believe this is in line with the philosophy of what you're trying to do. If you want to replicate what you're doing in the loop *exactly*, you can pad your image manually using the overlapping pixels that you'd take into account near the edge. You'd need to allocate a padded image of the right size, then manually slice the overlapping pixels of the original image in order to set the edge pixels in the padded result.

---

Since you mentioned that your images are huge and consequently padding leads to far too much memory use, you can avoid padding with some elbow grease. You can use slices of your huge image (which doesn't create a copy), but then you have to manually handle the edges where you don't have full slices. Here's how:

```
def get_patches(img, patchsize):
    """Compute patches on an input image without padding: assume "congruent" patches

    Returns an array shaped (npatch, 2) of patch pixel positions"""
    mx,my = (val//patchsize for val in img.shape[:-1])
    patched = img[:mx*patchsize, :my*patchsize, :].reshape(mx, patchsize, my, patchsize, 3)
    filt = ~(patched == 255).all((1, 3, 4))
    patch_x,patch_y = filt.nonzero() # patch indices of non-whites from 0 to nx-1, 0 to ny-1
    patch_pixel_x = patch_x * patchsize  # proper pixel indices of each pixel
    patch_pixel_y = patch_y * patchsize
    patches = np.stack([patch_pixel_x, patch_pixel_y], axis=-1)
    return patches

# fix the patches that fit inside the image
patches = get_patches(image, patchsize)

# fix edge patches if necessary
all_patches = [patches]
if imsize[0] % patchsize:
    # then we have edge patches along the first dim
    tmp_patches = get_patches(image[-patchsize:, ...], patchsize)
    # correct indices
    all_patches.append(tmp_patches + [imsize[0] - patchsize, 0])
if imsize[1] % patchsize:
    # same along second dim
    tmp_patches = get_patches(image[:, -patchsize:, :], patchsize)
    # correct indices
    all_patches.append(tmp_patches + [0, imsize[1] - patchsize])
if imsize[0] % patchsize and imsize[1] % patchsize:
    # then we have a corner patch we still have to fix
    tmp_patches = get_patches(image[-patchsize:, -patchsize:, :], patchsize)
    # correct indices
    all_patches.append(tmp_patches + [imsize[0] - patchsize, imsize[1] - patchsize])

# gather all the patches into an array of shape (npatch, 2)
patches = np.vstack(all_patches)

# if you also want to grab the actual patch values without looping:
xw, yw = np.mgrid[:patchsize, :patchsize]
patch_images = image[patches[:,0,None,None] + xw, patches[:,1,None,None] + yw, :]
# shape (npatch, patchsize, patchsize, 3),
# patch_images[i,...] is an image with patchsize * patchsize pixels
```

This will also exactly replicate your looping code, since we're explicitly taking the edge patches such that they overlap with the previous patches (there's no spurious white padding). If you want to have the patches in a given order you'll have to sort them now, though.

Comment: +1, great solution. Can you please elaborate this line `patched = padded.reshape(nx, patchsize, ny, patchsize, 3).transpose(0, 2, 1, 3, 4) `

Comment: @Shihab thanks. The first part (`padded.reshape(nx, patchsize, ny, patchsize, 3)`) does the actual chunking from a 2d array to a 4d collection of 2d patches (ignoring the colour channel dimension). Consider `arr = np.arange(2*3*4*3).reshape(2*3,4*3)`. Then `arr_chunked = arr.reshape(2,3,4,3)` is a similar chunked array: `arr_chunked[0,:,0,:]` is the 3-by-3 chunk at position `[0,0]` among chunks. `arr_chunked[0,:,1,:]` is the chunk next to this one to the right, and so on. In total there are 2*4 chunks `arr_chunked[i,:,j,:]`. The final transpose reorders the axes so that chunk indices are last.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I will test this soon and let you know if this is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: This looks fantastic, thanks a lot! Most of my images are of size `(39706, 94762, 3)` and the processing is done under a minute. The only downside is that it takes ~45GB of RAM, I'll have to find a way to reduce this number.

Comment: @E-Kami that's the usual business with vectorization: you trade memory for speed. You can gradually undo this trade-off by reintroducing some of the loops. What I'd do is first loop over the first index of patches. Something like `for iend in np.minimum(np.arange(patchsize - 1, nx * patchsize), imsize[0] - 1): subimg = image[iend-patchsize+1:iend+1, ...]` and do the same story just with padding along the second dimension of the subimage and gathering the patches in the loop. All the temporary arrays will be smaller, but we're adding a slow python loop in return.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the step in my previous comment: `np.arange(patchsize - 1, nx * patchsize, patchsize)`, give or take a few other off-by-one errors.

Comment: Thanks so much for this @AndrasDeak. I imagine if I introduce python loops again I could make use of numba to speed things up a bit

Comment: Hey @AndrasDeak . I was wondering if you had a solution to not use `np.pad` and instead use something which doesn't force me to resize my image because the patches created within this padding region are hard to deal with when I reconstruct my image. Also the `np.pad` seems to be responsible for the RAM overhead. Thanks!

Comment: @E-Kami eh, unaccepting an answer that solves your problem because you have issues with the specific implementation; smooth. I don't understand what you mean by "hard to deal with" patches. And yes, padding is responsible for the overhead. You can't do the above vectorization without padding. You can loop over both x and y dimensions and vectorize over patches.

Comment: @AndrasDeak sorry for that I didn't really know how to "open" the question again for answers. I reaccepted your answer and it'll stay that way, sorry for the trouble. So basically I have the choice to either do padding or to discard the patches at the edges, but no other solution right?

Comment: @E-Kami see my update; you can skip the padding if you do a bit more work. You'll still have to create a boolean array as large as your image in order to find white patches; you can only remove this memory overhead by reintroducing loops as I mentioned before.

Comment: Thank you so much @AndrasDeak !